# C++ automatic type deduction in constructor

Tags: c++, c++14

I am trying to understand the following code that I saw today. I already tried to find a related question, but since I have no idea what this feature of C++ is called it is hard to find related posts. A hint on the correct search term might already help me.

```
struct A
{ int x; };

struct B
{ B(A a) {}; };

int main()
{
    B b{ { 5 } }; // works, seems to create a struct A from {5} and pass it to B's constructor
    std::make_unique<B>({ 5 }); // doesn't compile
    return 0;
}
```

Why is `{5}` not used to create a struct A when passed to `make_unique` but is used this way in the constructor of `B`?

If B had a second constructor `B(int foo) {};` this one would be used instead of the one frome above (at least that is what I found by trial and error). What is the rule to decide if the argument is automatically used to create a `struct A` or if it is used directly as `int` in the constructor?

I am using Visual C++ 14.0

Comment: Look at [the signature of `make_unique`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique). The compiler has no way to know what `{ 5 }` should be in that context. There have been efforts to get `make_unique` (and others) to perform brace initialization when appropriate, which would negate the want for passing braces in the first place.

Comment: "Aggregate initialization" is probably a good term to [look up](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) as well as [list initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a simplified demonstration:

```
struct X { X(int); };

void foo(X );
template <typename T> void bar(T );

foo({0}); // ok
bar({0}); // error
```

The issue is that *braced-init-list*s, those constructs that are just floating `{...}`s, are strange beasts in C++. They don't have a type - what they mean must be inferred from how they're actually used. When we call `foo({0})`, the *braced-init-list* is used to construct an `X` because that's the argument - it behaves as if we wrote `X{0}`.

But in `bar({0})`, we don't have sufficient context to know what to do with that. We need to deduce `T` from the argument, but the argument doesn't have a type - so what type could we possibly deduce?

The way to make it work, in this context, is to explicitly provide that `T`:

```
bar<X>({0}); // ok
```

or provide an argument that has a type that can be deduced:

```
bar(X{0});   // ok
```

---

In your original example, you can provide the `A` directly:

```
make_unique<B>(A{5})
```

or the `B` directly:

```
make_unique<B>(B({5}))
```

or just use `new`:

```
unique_ptr<B>(new B({5}))
```

or, less preferred and somewhat questionable, explicitly specify the template parameter:

```
make_unique<B, A>({5});
```

Comment: The last one would practically kill any perfect forwarding, no?

Comment: @StoryTeller Not sure what you mean?

Comment: Doesn't specifying `A` inhibit the reference to it from being a forwarding reference? Just trying to imagine the questionable aspects of it.

Comment: @StoryTeller It's still a forwarding reference - just that its type is not deduced.

Comment: [Did a quick test](https://ideone.com/nj414Y), and it suggests it's not a forwarding reference. It's a regular rvalue reference. Doesn't matter much in this case (we only specified `A` for the brace init to begin with), but I'd still be wary of other corner cases.

Comment: @StoryTeller Well yeah, because it's not deduced. But it's still a forwarding reference.

Answer (score -2):

A constructor with a single non-default parameter (until C++11) that is declared without the function specifier `explicit` is called a converting constructor. Your `A` and `B` are instances of such constructors (this explains, why your first call works fine.) The problem is, that `std::make_unique` impedes these explicit calls. Anyhow, it might be a good idea, to not trust in these automatic creation in the first place and spent a few chars to show types. This could improve the readability of the code.

Comment: In the case of `make_unique`, it's rather unfortunate that you would have to repeat the type (or add a constructor, which can disable aggregateness). The type was given a few characters back, so at that point, it's needless repetition rather than any sort of readability improvement.

Comment: The type of B was given, but there is no way to guess, that 5 is actually a creation of A (that is passed to B) without reading the definition of B and I don't think that this will disable any performance improvements?

Comment: That's fair, I was applying it to the creation of `B` rather than `A`

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all?

Comment: I just want to encourage to not write code like this at all, because std::make_unique has this inconvenient property (that was outlined before.) My point is, that this is a know issue and it's better to avoid this by typing explicit type names.

Comment: @avitase - That "inconvenient property" is a strength of modern C++. Just because types are important doesn't mean you should go repeating them all over the place.